# golang connect 2 different type database at same time

Tags: go

I need to connect mysql and oracle at same time for a database related application. From the document I learned that in go the database drivers are initialized in "init()" function. So I want to know if I import 2 different database drivers, does the later driver will override the former one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem importing both because the drivers use different names. The driver name is the first argument to [sql.Open](https://godoc.org/database/sql#Open).

If they should happen to use the same name, then the  driver registration function [panics](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql.go#L45).